# How to scroll through items in a list using bezel in Samsung Tizen Gear s2?

Tags: javascript, scroll, rotation, ring, tizen-web-app

I have a question I have been dealing with for some time. I do web app development for gear s2.

What I want to do in my app is something exactly similar to what you do in the watch itself.

in ''settings'' for example, you have a vertical list and you can scroll through items by rotating the bezel.

i know according to this question [Rotarty (ring) on Samsung Tizen Gear S2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992667/rotarty-ring-on-samsung-tizen-gear-s2)
this event should be used:

```
 rotaryDetentCallback = function rotaryDetentHandler(e) {
    var direction = e.detail.direction;
    if (direction === "CW") {
        // TODO: do something

    } else if (direction === "CCW") {
        // TODO: do something

    }
};

window.addEventListener("rotarydetent", rotaryDetentCallback);
```

How can I make it work inside if() to scroll through the items in a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of list you want to display.

For static list items, the TAU framework already takes care of this for you. So you won't need anything on the script side to add.

Example of static content:

```html
<ul data-role="listview" >
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
</ul>
```

For dynamic content, this functionality is still buggy, but possible. You must update the content of your dynamic list in the `"pagebeforeshow"` (not `"pageshow"`). Once you do that, it will behave as if it is a static list.

Example of dynamic content:

in your html:

```
<ul id="myListView" data-role="listview" >
</ul>
```

in your js:

```js
page.addEventListener("pagebeforeshow", function () {
    var element = document.getElementById("myListView");
    var myListView = tau.widget.Listview(element);

    myListView.addItem("<li>item 1</li>", 1);
    myListView.addItem("<li>item 2</li>", 2);
    myListView.addItem("<li>item 3</li>", 3);
    myListView.addItem("<li>item 4</li>", 4);
    myListView.addItem("<li>item 5</li>", 5);
    myListView.addItem("<li>item 6</li>", 6);
    myListView.addItem("<li>item 7</li>", 7);
    myListView.addItem("<li>item 8</li>", 8);
});
```

I hope you'll find these examples useful.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I had a static listview and the bezel was not working on it so I thought my .js is not correct. but I just checked out a sample list and as you said it works already!

Comment: Hi @Armin. I've got another question. i have a simple page with 'text' content. Again I cannot scroll it up and down using the bezel. do you have any idea how this may be solved?
thanks.

Comment: Hi! I haven't tried that yet. I'd suggest posting that as a new question and when I find the answer, i'll answer it there.

Comment: I have a problem with dynamic list. When I try to addItem I got this error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'myListView.addItem("<li>item 1</li>", 1)')` . I've done the same implementation as above; but I still got an error. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This error means the `addItem` is not defined. This could be a result of the previous line where `myListView` is being created, not happening correctly. Since the myListView is being created by the `tau`, please make sure the  TAU library is loaded correctly and there are no errors in it.

Comment: I got the same undefined error, but the TAU library is correctly loaded (I can trace it and see that the object is valid). The myListView is a valid object too. Any ideas? thank you!